# PyParsing returns null token inconsistently

Tags: pyparsing

I have a pyparsing pattern that I'm applying to the same text string in two different environments (my local machine vs a Google Dataproc environment; both are using pyparsing 2.3.1), and I'm getting two slightly different outputs. Basically, when I run

```
MY_PATTERN.searchString(text)
```

on my local I get the expected result

```
[[['MY RESULT']]]
```

and when I run it on Dataproc (using the same exact pattern and text string input), I get

```
 [[<pyparsing._NullToken object at 0x7ff663d20208>, ['MY RESULT']]]
```

Any explanation for the difference?

Comment: I don't see any code path in which `_NullToken` would be returned from parsing. Is Dataproc using a modified version of pyparsing?

Comment: I explicitly set it to use pyparsing 2.3.1, which it should pull via pip.

Comment: Pyparsing uses a _NullToken() instance as a singleton to indicate that no default value has been provided to an Optional expression. Perhaps your program has imported pyparsing multiple times via different module paths, so that the singleton has multiple definitions.

Comment: Try this: `import pyparsing as pp;print(repr(pp._optionalNotMatched))` in your code, and see how this compares with the NullToken repr you get in your parsed results.

Comment: Same result from local and Dataproc: <pyparsing._NullToken object at 0x....>

Comment: Does the NullToken id on Dataproc match the one in the parsed resutls?

Comment: Nope, I get two different id - one for _optionalNotMatched and another for the returned ParseResults.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196276/discussion-between-paulmcg-and-john).

Comment: I believe I may have added the solution to this in the upcoming 2.4.2 release, but if my theory is correct, you may not see results until both you and Dataproc update to that release or later.